# How to give a "checkbox onChange event" the calling Input Id (in Xpages)

Tags: javascript, html, xpages, lotus-notes

I have an Xpages Application and I am currently using a checkbox in a repeat control to call an onChange function, I want to parse the calling element/elementID to my Client Side Javascript located in: Events->onChange. My problem is that my Javascript returns undefined when using "this". I tried to parse an object on the Function call but that doesnt seem to be possible in Xpages either.

Javascript Code (probably wont be much help):

```
var fieldsets = document.querySelectorAll("table.checkboxGroups");
console.log(fieldsets);
console.log("-----------------");

var fieldsetCurrent = fieldsets[0]; //this is where I need the calling elem

console.log(fieldsetCurrent);
console.log("-----------------");

var fieldsetCheckboxes = fieldsetCurrent.getElementsByTagName("input");
console.log(fieldsetCheckboxes);
console.log("-----------------");


for(i=0;fieldsetCheckboxes.length;i++){
    var elem = fieldsetCheckboxes[i];

    console.log(i + " : " +elem);

    elem.setAttribute("checked","");
    //elem.checked;
}
```

Comment: You should  probably show a snippet of your XPage with the repeat. That seems to be where you're having problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your repeating on notes documents then you could add the documentid to the checkbox as an attribute and use this id to call your onChange eventhandler. dojo.query might also be of some value here.